# How to make puppeteer wait for page redirect from Cloudflare browser check?

Tags: javascript, browser, puppeteer, cloudflare, ddos

I am scraping a website where after submitting a form I get redirected to this -

```
Checking your browser before accessing <Website Name>.
This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly.

Please allow up to 5 seconds…

DDoS protection by Cloudflare
Ray ID: <Some ID>
```

Now, usually when I myself submit that form manually from the "real web browser" I get redirected to the main contents almost immediately after this browser checking stuff appears. But in puppeteer, it doesn't.

I have tried to use `page.waitForNavigation()` but I couldn't get it to work.
Is there any way to actually get past this checking process? Or puppeteer is just getting blocked?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [puppeteer-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-extra) which enables you to add different plugins like `StealthPlugin` or `AdblockerPlugin`. Have a look at their documentation.

Comment: Also if anyone still has an issue after trying puppeteer-extra. Make sure puppeteer-core is not installed (remove it from node_modules and the package.json)

Answer (score 2):

You can wait for specific element on the web page. For example header or something.

Using `await page.waitForElement(selector);`

Comment: I tried it. Actually when I ran it in debug mode I found puppeteer was stuck in an endless loop in cloudflare redirects. `puppeteer-extra` solved it somehow